# Why does my own controller result in a 404 error?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-status-code-404

I am using the default preset project to build my own application upon it.
I have added my own controller `MyController` and a new view directory `My` with an `index.cshtml`.

This is the controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebProject1.Controllers
{
    public class MyController: Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /My/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my `RouteConfig.cs`:

```
// ...
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
// ...
```

However, when I start debugging and navigate to `/My/` an 404 error with a message along the lines of `The resource or one of its dependencies cannot be found.` is shown.

How do I make my controller work?

Comment: Please post your route code also. What is your default controller mentioned in the route?

Comment: Do you have Index view in place?

Comment: @HBhatia Yes i have created `/Views/My/Index.cshtml`.

Comment: The route also looks correct. Can you post the locations that The browser is searching for your views? Or did you check if the action Index was hit by keeping a breakpoint. Does it work if you type /my/index in the browser?

Comment: @ckv Hmm, no the `Index()` method in the controller isn't hit. Even when I manually type out the full URL.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: Did you try calling the /my/index url and check. Also please post the locations where all the file is being searched. Also can you try keeping the view outside the my folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly a typo somewhere. I'd suggest recreating your controller and views from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have any areas configured you should be able to access your action at 
`localhost/My/Index` or `localhost/My` if you have your default route with action as index.

The error will also give you the list of areas ASP.NET is searching to locate your view.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom route and put it before your default route.

like this:

```
    // ...
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
     routes.MapRoute(
           name: "me",
           url: "me/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
// ...
```

hope this works...